# Ajax Post to Controller - MVC4

Tags: jquery, post, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I can not get to the controller method. I think it may be the url, but I have tried different variations of it. I have been trying to figure this out for way too long.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ajaxCall", "ContactForm")',                          
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',                       
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify("test"),           
                    success: function () {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("fail");
                    }

                })
```

Here is my controller.

```
    namespace form.Controllers
    {
        public class ContactFormController : Controller
        {


            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ajaxCall(string s)
            {            
                return Content("");
            }
    }
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 issues with the example you provided.

1. The URL.Action method will return only `'/ContactForm/ajaxCall'` when what you need is the fully qualified URL (`'http://servername.com/ContactForm/ajaxCall'`)
2. The client javascript is expecting the server to send back JSON and your controller action is returning HTML. Change the controller action to return 'JsonResult' and it should work fine, I tested.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the word "Controller" in the call to `@Url.Action()`:

```
@Url.Action("ajaxCall", "ContactForm")
```

It's not looking for the class name, it's looking for the *controller* name, and in ASP.NET MVC convention the word "Controller" is part of the class name to indicate that it's a controller otherwise named "ContactForm" in this case.

Comment: @mwhite14: What's the response from the server?

Comment: It is never makes it to the server. It is going to the error function. The data value it gives it [object Object], not that it matters since it is not even getting to the server.

Comment: @mwhite14: What's the error that causes it to go to the error condition?  Are you sure it's not getting *some* response from the server?  If it's not even sending a *request* to the server then something must be wrong client-side.  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  Is there a network request at all?  How are you confirming that it's not going to the server?

Answer (score 0):

If David's answer doesn't get you all the way there (definitely look at the rendered page to see what it outputs to be sure), try wrapping the Razor code in braces:

```
@{Url.Action("ajaxCall", "ContactForm")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
url: '@Url.Action("ajaxCall", "ContactForm")
```

You shouldn't be specifying the full name of the controller class. You can also try the route name.

Comment: @mwhite14: Hard code the URL to eliminate that possibility. Then try to figure out what the specific error is. 
`code`
    error: function (error) {
        **alert('error; ' + eval(error));**
    }
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Try posting a javascript object like this:

```
var value = { s : 'Test string' }
```

And on the ajax call:

```
data: JSON.stringify(value)
```

So the model binder will find an 's' property to map to the 's' parameter.

According to the dataType ajax option, you should return a JsonResult from the action: this option is the expected type of response received from the server.